# Is site safe after a failed module installation?

Tags: installation

I was working on a site this morning, and I enabled a whole bunch of modules at the same time.  One of the modules threw a PDO exception during the process.

What state is the site in at this point?  Assuming the site still loads after the error, is it safe to use, or should I restore from a backup?

For the sake of this question, I am not concerned about the actual error or the module that threw the error (I would report this in the issue queue).  I am concerned about the general state of the site, and what may have happened to the installations of the other modules.

To make this more concrete, let's say I tried to enable ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC, and ModuleD.  After I clicked SUBMIT on the module page, ModuleC threw an uncaught PDO Exception and I didn't get the normal module enabled message.  Now, lets say that I can live without ModuleC on the site.  What can be said about the state of hpw the installation went for ModuleA, ModuleB, and ModuleD, and also dor Drupal in general?

Comment: It totally depends - what was the specific error message? What module were you installing?

Comment: @Clive I am thinking more in the general sense, but related to a real world problem.  In my case, it was easy enough to restore a backup.  I'll edit with some more detail later.

Comment: I think it'll be hard to answer that generally - the module might matter less, but a PDOException can be thrown for so many different things - an invalid query string, a temporary (or permanent) network failure, a full hard disk, messed up MySQL or server conf, a goat gnawing on the corner of the machine (not totally sure about the last one). I guess even knowing the 'genre' of the exception would be useful

Comment: I will uninstall the modules one by one, if i don't know about the error and that will fix the error mostly and it is safe. suppose if the site is completely dead, then i will restore the backup. it depends on the state. and it looks off topic or too broad here, i don't know why @Clive not mentioned this.

Comment: I tried to clarify this a bit.  The question isn't about the module that caused the error, it's about everything else.

Comment: first thing, it is not recommended to install bunch of modules at once and i think it will not install the remaining module, if suppose error occuted in module c, then it will not install the module d. i have experience same like this, but for my case module c with blank screen, then i checked the db it not installed the module d. module a&b are fine.

Comment: @Bala Do you have a source for that? If it's not recommended it seems strange that you can enable multiple modules at once. What happens when you need to install a module which _depends_ on 5 other modules that are currently disabled? That can't not be recommended (it's vital), but it would have exactly the same problem as enabling the same number of un-related modules

Comment: @MPD Could you go horribly low-tech and just check the watchdog? I think the very last thing done when a module is enabled is it writes the "xxx module enabled successfully" message to watchdog, so that should theoretically tell you which ones made it through

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it isn't. It may be, but it depends what's in module's `hook_install`.

First, most modules provide schema. The code of [`drupal_install_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/7) in 7 is currently:

```
function drupal_install_schema($module) {
  $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed($module);
  _drupal_schema_initialize($schema, $module, FALSE);

  foreach ($schema as $name => $table) {
    db_create_table($name, $table);
  }
}
```

As you can see, no call to [`db_translation`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_transaction/7), and each table is created one at a time. Now, if module only provides own schema, you are left with some garbage in database, but it's a well isolated garbage. But if it implements [`hook_schema_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) it's pretty possible you are left with some tables already altered, bu no code to handle these alterations. Now, in theory installing schema should never fail with PDO error, but due to RDBMS configuration for example, it may happen.

Second problem is that module's author can write pretty much anything in it's install code, and you are not guaranteed it will get rolled back at failed install. If he decides his module needs to change variables provided by core or other modules (for example to allow apparent conditional content, like with translated variables), or if it redefines some fields to provide additional functionality, you may end up with some of your data converted to module's format, and no longer accessible without it, or without running code meant to uninstall it.

---

Note: Situations above from experience. Even if I miss some theoretical part that should make them impossible to happen, they both did happened to me in real life. With -dev versions, but module version depends solely on it's author, so there is no guarantee that it will not happen in stable versions some day, too.